# Basic principles of a hashtable in java

Tags: java, hashtable

I am writing a java application for processing bank accounts. Consider the following classes:

```
public class Account 
{
    private double balance;
    private Person owner;
    private String currency;
    private Date openingDate;

    //constructors, getters, setters, other methods
}
```

and

```
public class Bank
{
    //Hashtable accounts;
    //....

    //testing hashtable operations      
    public static void main(String []args)
    {

        Person per1 = new Person(1,"Andrei","Moldovan","str. Lunga nr.4");
        Account acc1 = new Account(per1);
        Account acc2 = new Account(per1, "USD");

        Person p3 = new Person(3,"Erich","Serfozo","str. Zorilor nr. 11");
        Account acc3 = new Account(p3,"EUR");
        acc3.deposit(110.50);

        Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
        hash.put(acc1.hashCode(), acc1);
        hash.put(acc2.hashCode(), acc2);
        hash.put(acc3.hashCode(), acc3);

        Collection hashtableValues = hash.values();

        for(Object iter : hashtableValues)
        {
           Account acc = (Account)iter;
           System.out.println(acc.toString());
        }  

    }
}
```

The Bank class uses a Hashtable to store every account it contains. Which is the proper way to insert/access Accounts into/from the hashtable? (I know I'm not doing in right) In case of collision, I want to use chaining.

Comment: how you want to retrieve your bank account records, by person ? or by bank account id ?

Comment: Each account should have a unique ID that you can also use as your key. Also, consider using a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: @Jigar Joshi then i should add in the Account class an instance variable accountId, a getter for it, and use something like hash.put(acc1.getId(),acc1)?

Comment: Yes make sure the key implements hashcode and equals properly, also value implements equals correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do more research into the standard Java collections, as you seem a bit confused about what you want, and you seem to be fixated on the old `Hashtable` class and its internal implementation.

The theory behind a *map*, which is what both the old `Hashtable` and the modern `HashMap` are, is that it maps from a specific *key* to a single *value*. The map either *contains* a key or does not. If it does contain a key, you can *get* the value associated with the key.

The way in which the hash table operates should be opaque to you. A flat list of key->value pairs could be searched and you'd get the same result. The hash table improves on the speed of this operation by using a *hash code*, which can be literally any number, provided it's consistently the same number for the same key. It doesn't matter if more than one *different key* has the same hash code, because the table uses `.equals` on potential keys in the table to make sure it got exactly the right one. But the more specific the hash code, the less likely there is to be more than one key to check.

You should be more concerned with what you want to store, what you want to retrieve. Do you want to look up accounts by their account number? Do you want to look up accounts by who owns them? You need to design your data structures in response to that need.

For example, to handle looking up which accounts a person has (and a person can have more than one account), you could make a `Map` that maps from a `Person` (the key) to a *set* of `Account`s:

```
final Map<Person, Set<Account>> accountsByPerson = new HashMap<>();

// add account acc1 for a person per1
Set<Account> accountsForThisPerson = accountsByPerson.get(per1);
if (accountsForThisPerson == null) {
    accountsForThisPerson = new HashSet<>();
    accountsByPerson.put(per1, accountsForThisPerson);
}
accountsForThisPerson.add(acc1);

// retrieve one person's accounts:
final Set<Account> accountsOfPerson1 = accountsByPerson.get(per1);
if (per1 == null) {
    System.out.println(per1 + " has no accounts");
}
else {
    System.out.println(per1 + " has " + accountsOfPerson1.size() + " account(s)");
    for (final Account a : accountsOfPerson1) {
        System.out.println(perl + " has account " + a);
    }
}
```

This code presumes that both `Account` and `Person` implement an `equals` and `hashCode` method that always gives the right answer: if I have two different objects that represent the same account, `equals` says they are the same and `hashCode` gives the same result for both of them, and once I put them into a structure like a HashMap or HashSet, their `hashCode` does not change.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique id for each account that you assign to people you can do this:

```
//if you want to use a HashMap, then instantiate like below
HashMap<Integer, Account> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Account>();

hash.put(acc1.getId(), acc1);

//to get Account from Person from map
hash.get(per1.getAccountId());

//iterating
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Account> entry : hash.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue().getPerson());
}
```

Comment: And since my accountId is unique, do i still have to worry about collision?

Comment: If each account id is unique, then you won't see any collision. But let's say you assign two people the same account id. If that happens and you call `put(1, acc1)` and then call `put(1,acc2)`, then acc1 would be removed from the map. If you called `get(1)` in this example, it'd return acc2.

Comment: I did as you said and it seems to work. But when i try to iterate through every entry in my hashmap, i get a NullPointerException after the last element. How should i fix that?

Comment: It is posted above, using a collection and iterating through it.

Comment: [Check out the top answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map), but don't forget to change the Types, like `Map.Entry<Integer, Account>`.

Answer (score 0):

Each account can be associated with unique number (it may be the account number or some other value) and this can be :

```
hash.put(acc1.getAcntNum(), acc1);

hash.(acc1.getIdentifier,acc1);
```

Other way could be, make person id as key and value would have list of accounts that a person have:List list = new ArrayList();list.add(acnt1);list.add(acnt2);
hash.put(person.getId(),list);
By this managing all the accounts for an user would be easier.